# Linker error in GLSL shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I am writing a program using shaders and getting some error when running the built exe.

> Shader program failed to link
>
> The fragment shader uses varying color, but previous shader does not write to it.
>
> Out of resource error.

This is my code:

example.cpp:

```
// Two-Dimensional Sierpinski Gasket       
// Generated using randomly selected vertices and bisection

#include "Angel.h"

const int NumTimesToSubdivide = 5;
const int NumTetraeder = 1024;
const int NumVertices = 9 * NumTetraeder;

vec4 points[NumVertices];
int Index = 0;

int fps = 20;
float angle_param = 0.5;

float etime;
GLint time_loc;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


void triangle(const vec4& a, const vec4& b, const vec4& c)
{
   points[Index++] = a;
   points[Index++] = b;
   points[Index++] = c;
}

void divide_tetraeder(const vec4& a, const vec4& b, const vec4& c, const vec4& d, int count)
{
   if(count > 0)
   {
      //compute midpoints
      vec4 ab = (a + b) / 2.0;
      vec4 ac = (a + c) / 2.0;
      vec4 ad = (a + d) / 2.0;

      vec4 bc = (b + c) / 2.0;
      vec4 bd = (b + d) / 2.0;

      vec4 cd = (c + d) / 2.0;

      divide_tetraeder( a, ab, ac, ad, count -1);
      divide_tetraeder(ab,  b, bc, bd, count -1);
      divide_tetraeder(ad, bd, cd,  d, count -1);
      divide_tetraeder(ac, bc,  c, cd, count -1);        

   }
   else
   {
      triangle(a,b,c);
      triangle(b,d,c);
      triangle(d,a,c);
   }
}

void
init( void )
{
    // Specifiy the vertices for the initial tetraeder

    vec4 vertices[4] = {
        vec4(  0.0,   -1.0, -1.0,  1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.866, -1.0,  0.5,  1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.0,    1.0,  0.0,  1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.866, -1.0,  0.5,  1.0 )
    };


    divide_tetraeder(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2], vertices[3], NumTimesToSubdivide);

    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "../shader/vshader_03.glsl", "../shader/fshader_03.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

    //Initialize the time parameter
    time_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "time");

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); // white background
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
display( void )
{
  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   // clear the window    
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );    // draw the points
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch ( key ) {
    case 033:
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        break;
    }
}

void specialKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key ) {
   case GLUT_KEY_UP:
      fps += 1;
      std::cout << "fps: " << fps << std::endl;
      break;

   case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
      if(fps > 1) fps -= 1;
      std::cout << "fps: " << fps << std::endl;
      break;

   case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
      angle_param -= 0.05;
      std::cout << "angle_param: " << angle_param << std::endl;
      break;

   case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
       angle_param += 0.05;
       std::cout << "angle_param: " << angle_param << std::endl;
       break;
   default:
      break;
   }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


void timer(int value){

    static float currentangle = 0.0f;
    currentangle += angle_param;

    float angle = currentangle*DegreesToRadians; // small angle in radians

    //**************************************************************
    //Füge hier deinen code ein, der die Punkte um die z-Achse dreht und neu zur Grafikkarte hochlädt

    //Benutze die Funktion RotateY um eine 4x4 Rotationsmatrix zu erzeugen
    mat4 rotMat = RotateY(angle);

    //Berechne die rotierten Vertices auf der CPU durch Multiplikation mit der Matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < NumVertices; i++) {
        points[i] = rotMat * points[i];
    }   
    
    //Anzahl der Sekunden seit dem letzten Aufruf
    //http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node70.html
    etime = 0.001 * glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

    //Schicke diesen Wert zum Vertex Shader
    glUniform1f(time_loc, etime);

    //Sende alle Vertices erneut an die GPU
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    //*******************************************************************/
    
    glutPostRedisplay();
    int delay = ceil(1000.0f / fps);
    glutTimerFunc( delay,timer,0);   
}

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    // If you are using freeglut, the next two lines will check if 
    // the code is truly 3.2. Otherwise, comment them out
    //glutInitContextVersion( 3, 1 );
    //glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
        
    glutCreateWindow( "Sierpinski Gasket" );

    glewInit();
    
    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutSpecialFunc( specialKeys );

    int delay = ceil(1000.0f / fps);
    glutTimerFunc( delay,timer,0);
    

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

InitShader.cpp:

```
#include "Angel.h"

char vSource[] = "#version 130\n in vec4 vPosition;\nvoid main() {\n    gl_Position = vPosition;\n}\n";
char fsource[] = "#version 130\n out vec4 color;\n void main() {\n   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n}\n";

namespace Angel {

// Create a NULL-terminated string by reading the provided file
static char*
readShaderSource(const char* shaderFile)
{
    //öffne die Datei
    FILE* fp = fopen(shaderFile, "r");

    //wenn das nicht klappt, hör sofort auf
    if ( fp == NULL ) { return NULL; }

    //finde heraus wie groß in bytes die datei ist
    //1. gehe zum ende der datei
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    //2. frage nach der Größe
    long size = ftell(fp);

    //mache einen speicherbereich für den shadertext von ausreichender Größe
    char* buf = new char[size + 1];

    //gehe zum Anfang der datei
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    //lies das erste Zeichen
    char c;
    c = fgetc(fp);

    //initialisiere den index für den buffer
    int i = 0;

    //Solange das Ende der Datei nicht erreicht ist
    while(c != EOF)
    {
       //Zeichen abspeichern
       buf[i] = c;
       //Nächstes Zeichen lesen
       c = fgetc(fp);
       //index für den Puffer inkrementieren
       i++;
    }    

    //Am Ende den Puffer mit 0 terminieren 
    buf[i] = '\0';

    //Datei schließen
    fclose(fp);

    //printf("buf is: %s",buf);
    return buf;
}


// Create a GLSL program object from vertex and fragment shader files
GLuint
InitShader(const char* vShaderFile, const char* fShaderFile)
{
    struct Shader {
    const char*  filename;
    GLenum       type;
    GLchar*      source;
    }  shaders[2] = {
    { vShaderFile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, NULL },
    { fShaderFile, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL }
    };

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
        Shader& s = shaders[i];
        
        s.source = readShaderSource( s.filename );
        if ( shaders[i].source == NULL ) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read " << s.filename << std::endl;
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        
      /*
        if(i==0) s.source = vSource;
        else s.source = fsource;
      */

        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( s.type );

        glShaderSource( shader, 1, (const GLchar**) &s.source, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );

        GLint  compiled;
        glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled );
        if ( !compiled ) {
            std::cerr << s.filename << " failed to compile:" << std::endl;
            GLint  logSize;
            glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize );
            char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
            glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, logSize, NULL, logMsg );
            std::cerr << logMsg << std::endl;
            delete [] logMsg;

            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //delete [] s.source;

        glAttachShader( program, shader );
    }

    /* link  and error check */
    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint  linked;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked );
    if ( !linked ) {
    std::cerr << "Shader program failed to link" << std::endl;
    GLint  logSize;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize);
    char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
    glGetProgramInfoLog( program, logSize, NULL, logMsg );
    std::cerr << logMsg << std::endl;
    delete [] logMsg;

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    /* use program object */
    glUseProgram(program);

    return program;
}

}  // Close namespace Angel block
```

vshader_03.glsl:

```
#version 130

uniform float time;
in vec4 vPosition;
void main()
{

    vec4 temp = vPosition;
    temp.x *= (1+sin(time));
    gl_Position = temp;
}
```

fshader_03.glsl:

```
#version 130
in vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of your shaders? Given a quick look at your code I thought it was the strings vSource and fSource but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @pleluron added shader contents now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your fragment shader has a varying variable `in vec4 color`, but none of the preceding shader stages (the vertex shader in your case) does define an varying output `out vec4 color`. This is also what the error message told you. Solution: Your vertex shader must define a `out vec4 color` and write to it.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks!